# vimspell mappings don't work

Tags: vim, spell-check

I've installed vimspell. It works via the command mode commands like :SpellCheck, but I can't get any of the mappings to work.

:map shows

```
n  \ss           <Plug>SpellCheck
```

This is how it's supposed to be, since \ is my  key, and the macro should execute in normal mode. If I change the leader key in my .vimrc, the mappings update properly too.

For some reason, when I type \ss, it just replaces the current character with s like typing ss would, as if I didn't press \

Why might this mapping not be working?

Does anyone else use vimspell (from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=465) and have it working? or is there a better way to do spell checking in vim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use this feature often.  Maybe you could explain why the default :spell wasn't enough for you?

Regarding your problem, how did you change the leader to `\`?  Did you follow [these instructions](http://hermitte.free.fr/vim/VS_help.html#g:VS_map_leader)?

There is nothing to map to `<Plug>SpellCheck`.  The documentation indicates defining a mapping for *show* as  [`<Plug>VS_showE`](http://hermitte.free.fr/vim/VS_help.html#VS_map_leader).

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't aware of :spell. That seems to do what I need. Thanks!